# Serenity shows test as pending

Tags: selenium, gradle, jbehave, serenity-bdd

I am new to automation and am trying to automate some of our UI test cases using selenium and jbehave. A basic test seems to work fine. 
Now I have a story file that has 2 scenarios, and each scenario has steps defined in multiple files. 
When I run this test case, it shows.

Test ignored.
Test ignored.
Test ignored.
Test ignored.
Test ignored.[pool-1-thread-1] INFO net.serenitybdd.core.Serenity - TEST PENDING

I saw a similar question here but no answers on that. Can anyone help me with this?

Serenity-bdd :version 1.1.36

Update:
My folder structure is like
test
    java/...
        accounts
            steps
                AccountsSteps
                UserSteps
            test
                AccountsTest
                AccountTest
                UserTest
    resources/...
        accounts
            test
                accounts_test.story
                user_test.story

Here is my Testclass with JUnitStory. This looks at the steps file AccountsSteps and execute it correctly.

```
@RunWith(JUnitReportingRunner.class)
public class AccountsTest extends JUnitStory {
    private WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    @Override
    public Configuration configuration() {
        return new MostUsefulConfiguration()
                .useStoryLoader(new LoadFromClasspath(this.getClass()))
                .useStoryReporterBuilder(new StoryReporterBuilder()
                        .withReporters(new MyStoryReporter())
                        .withDefaultFormats().withFormats(StoryReporterBuilder.Format.CONSOLE, StoryReporterBuilder.Format.HTML, StoryReporterBuilder.Format.STATS));
    }

    @Override
    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
        return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), new AccountsSteps(driver));
    }
}
```

I tried adding a class like below with SerenityStories which would look at all the stories under accounts/test

```
@RunWith(JUnitReportingRunner.class)
public class AccountTest extends SerenityStories {

    public AccountTest() {
        findStoriesIn("**//accounts/test");
    }
}
```

The console shows all the stories/scenarios in that folder, but shows all the tests as Ignored.

Comment: can you share your code ?

Comment: I am sorry, since I couldnt figure it out, I deleted it all and decided to take one at a time. First selenium and junit. Once I have a handle of it, then will start with  jbehave and serenity

Answer (score 0):

Check the build log/console output for the word "pending".  You may have steps that aren't implemented yet.

If that's the case you'll get a helpful message showing you what the method should look like eg :

```
You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

@Given("^I am landing page$") public void i_am_landing_page() throws Throwable {
     // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
     throw new PendingException(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have all the steps implemented. And when I run the individual story files with JUnitStory, they all work fine. But when I try using serenity story everything is marked pending.

Answer (score 0):

You have to indicate the stepdefinitions route as code below

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.SnippetType;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    plugin = {"pretty"},
    features = "src/test/resources/features",
    glue = "stepdefinitions",
    snippets= SnippetType.CAMELCASE     )
public class CucumberTestSuite {
}
```